# Receiving two push notifications by sending only one

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having a problem with my Firebase Messaging, basically it gets the push both by the console of Firebase and behind the FCM but it receives two push notification even sending only one, and I have no idea what might be happening this, I've seen some solutions but nothing solves, has anyone ever gone through it? Follow the code of implementation.

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMlIj.png)

custom_firebase_messaging.dart

```
class CustomFirebaseMessaging {
  final CustomLocalNotification _customLocalNotification;
  
  CustomFirebaseMessaging._internal(this._customLocalNotification);
  static final CustomFirebaseMessaging _singleton = CustomFirebaseMessaging._internal(CustomLocalNotification());
  factory CustomFirebaseMessaging() => _singleton;

  Future<void> inicialize() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(badge: true, sound: true, alert: true);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        _customLocalNotification.androidNotification(notification, android);
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      if (message.data['route'] != null) {
        NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(message.data['route']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

custom_local_notification.dart

```
class CustomLocalNotification {
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;

  CustomLocalNotification() {
    channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel',
      'High Importance Notifications',
      description: 'This channel is used for important notifications',
      importance: Importance.max,
    );

    _configureAndroid().then(
      (value) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = value;
        inicializeNotifications();
      },
    );
  }

  Future<FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin> _configureAndroid() async {
    final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    return flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  }

  Future<void> inicializeNotifications() async {
    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      const InitializationSettings(android: android),
    );
  }

  Future<void> androidNotification(
      RemoteNotification notification, AndroidNotification android) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          icon: android.smallIcon,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My start page, startup.dart

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  log("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

Future<void> start() async {
  runZonedGuarded(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    await CustomFirebaseMessaging().inicialize();

    FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError;

    runApp(const App());
  }, (error, stack) => FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack));
}
```

My implementation of FCM.

```
 void sendPushMessage(String title, String body, String token) async {
    try {
      await Dio().post(
        'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        options: Options(
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization':
                'myKey',
          },
        ),
        data: jsonEncode(
          <String, dynamic>{
            "to": token,
            "notification": {
              "title": title,
              "body": body,
            },
            "data": {
              "channelId": "session_alert",
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      log("Error push notification");
    }
  }
```

I have tried this solution, but on the contrary it does not send the message via FCM.

```
{
"to" : user_token,
"notificaton": {}, // remove this 
"data" : {
    "channelId":"session_alert",
    "title":"message title",
    "body":"message body",
}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you've assigned the device token to two topics?

Comment: If you send FCM with notification you don't have to fire flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show() method, only if you are sending data only message (with no notification key). The firebase package handles it for you :)

Comment: @HunterBooks I don't think so, because analyzing my code everything indicates that it is being writing to only one topic

Comment: @CsabaGergely How could I do that? Would you be able to give me an example?

Comment: @CsabaGergely Now I understood the concept thank you very much, I managed to make it work by passing the date and assigning a simple string inside the show method.